# how to use self-joints in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've the following Category model :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :categories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

and I want to be able to filter by parent category and select the parent category in add / edit categories

Comment: I think there is an error in the model. I think you mean :foreing_key => 'child_id' in the has_many method.

Comment: It works fine when I use it in rails console as no need for child_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with column 'name', as ActiveAdmin is looking for column 'name', but in my case I don't have this column. So, I update my model to have 'name' method. Then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure what you need exactly, but if you have a parent category id, then you can filter just by doing:

```
Category.where(:parent_id => parent_category_id)
```

Comment: Where should I add this ? Here's the filters manual http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html